# How to export QUASAR static folders (css, fonts, icons, js & favicon.ico) to custom FLASK static subfolder

Tags: vue.js, flask, webpack, quasar-framework

I am working on a single page application in QUASAR that I'd like to make available from a FLASK web-app.

I am struggling to distribute the QUASAR app's file, upon `quasar build`, so that the static files are copied in a subfolder of the Flask `static` folder while the html file is copied in a subfolder of the Flask `templates` folder. See below.

```
FOLDER STRUCTURE:

[backend]
- [static]
-- [my_app]        <- I'd like this 
--- [css]
--- [fonts]
--- [icons]
--- [js]
--- favicon.ico
- templates
-- [my_app]    <- and this
--- index.html
...

[frontend]
- [src]
-- ...
-- App.vue
- quasar.config.js
...
```

My two attemtps consisted in editing the `quasar.config.js`.

**1st attemp**: In the `build` object of the `quasar.config.js`, I've set `distDir` to the `static` folder of the Flask app. Then, I've set the `htmlFilename` property to the correct path into the `templates` Flask folder.

```
build: {
      vueRouterMode: 'hash', // available values: 'hash', 'history'
      distDir: '../backend/static/my_app/',
      htmlFilename: '../backend/templates/my_app/index.html'
      ...
}
```

Files are placed correctly, but refs in the `index.html` files to js, css, icons, images are all broken (i.e., they refer to the general configuration according to which static files are placed in the same folder of the html file).

**2nd attempt**: The `distDir` points to '../backend/templates/my_app/', but I try to move the other static files with this code of which I am not completely aware of.

```
build: {
      vueRouterMode: 'hash', // available values: 'hash', 'history'
      distDir: '../backend/templates/my-app/',
      
      chainWebpack: webpackConfig => {
         // ---> This works and move all js files in the correct folder and changes refs in index.html correctly!
         webpackConfig
           .output
           .filename('../../static/my-app/js/[name].js')
           .chunkFilename('../../static/my-app/js/chunk[id].[chunkhash:8].js')

         // ---> This works and copy (not move!) files from templates/my-app/css to static/my-app/css of the Flask app
         webpackConfig.plugin('mini-css-extract-plugin')
           .use(MiniCssExtractPlugin, [{
             filename: '../../static/my-app/css/[name].[contenthash:8].css',
             chunkFilename: "../../static/my-app/css/[name].[id].css",
             ignoreOrder: false,
           }])

         // ---> This works, but read below for refs issues
         webpackConfig.module
          .rule('fonts')
            .use('url-loader')
              .tap((args) => {
                args.name = '../../static/my-app/fonts/[name].[hash:8].[ext]';
                return args;
              })
              .end()
            .end()
          .end();

        // ---> This copy only svg files into the static/my-app/assets folder and not all images I'd like to copy
        webpackConfig.module
        .rule('images')
            .test(/\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|ico)(\?.*)?$/)
            .use('url-loader')
            .loader('file-loader?limit=100000')
            .options({
              name: '../../static/my-app/assets/[name].[ext]?[hash]',
            })   
}
```

At the end, I get this [refs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCuKt.png) in the index.html file:
1- js refs are OK
2- css refs are OK, but links to css in the `templates` folder remain
3- png and ico files are neither moved to the `static/my-app/assets` folder nor properly linked in the `index.html` file
4- fonts seem to be properly moved in the `static/my-app/assets` but when I run the flask app, I get

```
127.0.0.1 - - [11/May/2023 17:12:44] "GET /templates/my-app/static/my-app/fonts/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNcIhQ8tQ.c5371cfb.woff2 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [11/May/2023 17:12:44] "GET /templates/my-app/static/my-app/fonts/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxM.f1e2a767.woff HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [11/May/2023 17:12:44] "GET /templates/my-app/static/my-app/fonts/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNa.4d73cb90.woff HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Is there anybody can help me solve this issue? thanks